# random products in list.phtml template in magento

Tags: magento

Below is the code to get list of products on a category page in list.phtml.

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
```

I want another section below this list where I can list  random products of any category.
can I do something to tweek this same function and reuse it ?

It would be really easy if I could use the same helper.

I wanted a section for " you might be intrested in these " and I show random products there.

Thanks 
Ab

Answer (score 1):

I can't imagine something in Magento being as simple as:

```
shuffle($_productCollection);
```

Answer (score 0):

In XML where you should define your block, something like this:

```
<block type="catalog/product_list_random" template="your random template" name="random" />
```

and in the category view page simply make call to your template like

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('random');
```